# Django how to create errors while adding new objects

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools, django-admin-actions

See first the code.

models.py

```
class Schauspieler(models.Model):
    schauspieler = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.schauspieler
```

admin.py

```
class SchauspielerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('schauspieler',)

admin.site.register(Schauspieler, SchauspielerAdmin)
```

[localhost schauspieler tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajkis.png)

You can see i have there 2 time the name Alexander Ludwig. This is a list of actors in the admin. Because the names of the actors are too much, I do not remember which ones i have created and which ones not.
If the name exists than should come a error while adding.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the `schauspieler` *unique*, with [**`unique=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique):

```
class Schauspieler(models.Model):
    schauspieler = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.schauspieler
```

You probably however will *first* need to remove the already existing duplicates, since otherwise the database will reject the migration, because at that moment in time there *are* already duplicates.

Comment: ok thanks but can you show me a example for how to doing that for next times?

Comment: @Amir: if you create a new record with the same `schauspieler`, the database will reject it, and the admin will also show an exception...